# How to train data of different dimensions

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I want to train a model based on different datasets. The datasets consists of data of different dimensions. For example, in NLP, sentences are of different length. To not waste the computation resources, I don't want to pad 0s to make them the same dimensions. How do I do that?

I have tried multiple approaches.

1. For loop. My pseudo code is as follows:

```
model = ...
for dataset in datasets:
    model.fit(dataset)
    gc.collect()
```

Unfortunately the memory (not GPU memory) rapidly runs out, even with explicit garbage collection.

2. Generator for datasets. Unfortunately it is hard to define the shape function, etc.

Many thanks!

Comment: Garbage collection on GPU doesn't work the same way. It basically won't free any memory until the whole process exits. Try reducing the batch size to prevent OOM.

Comment: To clarify, it is the memory, not GPU memory, which runs out.